Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE]
has anyone seen this error before?
I'm trying this function. I'm basically trying to update the field "date" with the function date_add(date, lead_time). Here lead_time is a field which has int data type.
So, basically, I have a put a filtering where if location = Warehouse, then it should go ahead and do the date_add function. I can't hard-code the lead_time values as those are different for deliveries. Does anyone knows a hacky way to get this working?
Example:
date;lead_time
2024-05-19;2

date_add(date, lead_time)

Should give -> 2024-05-21
Would be really helpful If I could get some help. Thanks :)
I tried fetching from the field but getting the error mentioned my title description.

type cast your column and then do that. it'll work  @topbin123
